# Ubuntu cross compiling: install host or target dependencies in sysroot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linker, cross-compiling, toolchain

I'm trying to cross-compile an application for arm64 on Ubuntu 20.04 that depends on 3rd-party libraries like grpc. I think I need to install those dependency libraries in my cross-compiler's sysroot, so the cross compiling toolchain can find them. (Right?) Should I install dependencies built for the host system or the target system? I'm not sure if the cross-linker will expect arm64 (target) binaries to link with.

Comment: Why would you want to install host binaries? What role do they play in the final product?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI  I'm talking about shared objects, so either way, the binaries on the host won't be compiled into the cross-compiled executable. But I suppose if they were statically linked, they'd have to be target compiled. So is the answer that I install target-compiled shared objects in the cross compiling host?

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are shared or static, host-compiled binaries just don't come into play. Target ones of course.